# how to get the form value updated in angular 4 material with binding in place

Tags: angular, angular-material2

```
import {Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-configurable-example',
  templateUrl: 'checkbox-configurable-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['checkbox-configurable-example.css'],
})
export class CheckboxConfigurableExample {
  @ViewChild('formData') formData: NgForm;


  checked = false;
  indeterminate = false;
  align = 'start';
  disabled = false;

  imcheckedVal = false;
  changeCheck(){
    this.imcheckedVal = this.formData.value.check4
  }

}
```

template

```
<form #formData = 'ngForm'>
  <md-card>
    <md-card-content>
      <h2 class="example-h2">Checkbox configuration</h2>

      <section class="example-section">
        <md-checkbox name ='check1' class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="checked">Checked</md-checkbox>
        <md-checkbox name ='check2' class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="indeterminate">Indeterminate</md-checkbox>
      </section>

      <section class="example-section">
        <label class="example-margin">Align:</label>
        <md-radio-group  name ='radGroup' [(ngModel)]="align">
          <md-radio-button name ='rad1' class="example-margin" value="start">Start</md-radio-button>
          <md-radio-button name ='rad2' class="example-margin" value="end">End</md-radio-button>
        </md-radio-group>
      </section>

      <section class="example-section">
        <md-checkbox  name ='check3' class="example-margin" [(ngModel)]="disabled">Disabled</md-checkbox>
      </section>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>

  <md-card class="result">
    <md-card-content>
      <h2 class="example-h2">Result</h2>

      <section class="example-section">
        <md-checkbox name ='check4' ngModel
            class="example-margin"
            [checked]="checked"
            [indeterminate]="indeterminate"
            [align]="align"
            [disabled]="disabled">
          I'm a checkbox
        </md-checkbox>
      </section>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
</form>
<button (click) = 'changeCheck()'>get checkbox value</button>
Check box vaue is: {{imcheckedVal}}


<!-- Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/fhWWH3Mr994zn1vXKVAT?p=preview

In the above link there i have copied the angular material example and modified to suit my needs.

There is a form element at the top which is used later to retrieve data.

The problem is if u click the first checkbox, the checkbox in result at bottom gets selected but the value of the form element isn't changed u can see this by clicking the button at bottom. The form value only changes if u manually click the bottom checkbox. How do i get the form value to change with the bind in place

Comment: Not sure what the point is, but you can simply bind the last checkbox to the same model value as the first one:[(ngModel)]="checked".

Comment: all checkboxes are having `checked` as the `ngModel` so you will get like tat only

Comment: i cant bind it to the first as my current scenario is like a table with multiple checkbox with a parent checkbox to select all. So if i select the first checkbox rest all checks and i can manually uncheck the individual options too. the problem is the form value only has values on the ones clicked not changed through binding

Comment: Please add your goal (check all check box) to the question - I have an solution [in this plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Pf0n1pOAWl5hGaJfQqJR) which if that is what you want I'll add an the answer

Comment: this is the behaviour which i want but the solution is something which i had thought through. I was hoping if there is a way to update the form.value without calling a map or some loop. I have a complex structure which builds form from a db with lots of mapping so can't have a predefined array map. The last option would be to create a map on the fly but was hoping angular has some inbuilt function to update its value

Comment: with a complex, dynamic structure as you describe - you would probably be better using [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following to get the value:

```
<md-checkbox name ='check4' [(ngModel)]="checked" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Dean Chalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328848/dean-chalk) metions you just have to add both **[(ngModel)]** as well as **name** attributes to your material component here is a code snipet that might give you an idea.

component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
 <input matInput [value]="selectedWell.permit_date" 
 [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Permit Date:"
 [(ngModel)]="selectedWell.permit_date"
 name="selectedWell.permit_date">
 <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
 <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>

...

<button mat-button (click)="SaveWellDetails()" color="primary">Primary</button>
```

component.ts

```
import ...
@Component({
...
})
export class WellSearchComponent implements OnInit {
...
SaveWellDetails()
{
  console.log(this.selectedWell);
}
```

With this you will have the updated object in within the button's click methof, remember that in the end the task is easy, you just have to let know your view with the model they are supposed to be binded from angular will do the rest, notice the material2 material4 syntax **[()]**